# Словари JS и глобальные переменные

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

хочу передать переменную window.globalVar из функции(функция меняет значение переменной при наведении на элемент), но не получается не могу понять в чем причина, заранее благодарен

```
    window.globalVar = null;
    $.miniMenu = null;
    $(document).ready(function(){

var  project_li = $(".project-li"),
     Project_BG = $("#Project-Desc-BG"),
     project_body = $(".project-desc-body");

    project_li.on("mouseover", function taca() {
        project_li.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        project_body.removeClass('active');
        $($(this).attr("data-target-project")).addClass('active');

        Project_BG.css({'background-image' : $(this).attr("data-target-bg")});
      window.globalVar= $(this).attr("data-target-bg");
          //console.log(window.globalVar); //тут работает
        Project_BG.css({'background-size' : $(this).attr("cover")});
        Project_BG.css({'z-index' : $(this).attr("z")});

    });
});
 console.log(window.globalVar); // тут не работает
```

Comment: порядок выполнения залогируйте и увидите почему

Comment: дайте код пожалуйста, я не понимаю

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready` - асинхронный кусок кода, он запускается и код вне блока идет дальше, поэтому `console.log(window.globalVar)` срабатывает до изменения `window.globalVar`

Comment: как мне написать код, я не понимаю, можете пнуть меня, желательно код дать, если не трудно

Answer (score 0):

Как ответил Shiki, функция ready срабатывает гораздо позже, чем срабатывает логирование в консоль. JS в данном случае не синхронный, то есть функция ready может сработать допустим через час или никогда. И её данные можно передать только в функцию, которая будет вызвана внутри ready. Тут как-бы рождается новый поток выполнения, а в старый вернуться уже нельзя. Самый простой ответ на ваш вопрос - поднять консоль-лог на пару строчек выше внутрь ready.